# How to do a negative form validation in codeigniter?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

`is_unique` is the form validation which not allow the value exist in the database. 
But, can I do the opposite one? for example, I would like to need the value which is exist
in the database, so, I make the rules like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|max_length[32]|valid_email|(!(is_unique[users.email]))');
```

But it seems not success as I expected, any recommends? Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way is to write a new `is_unique`-like function, like `is_present` and amend the validation logic to handle it.

Comment: I would do a separate rule for is unique in model. and catch the result in controller. then I'll reverse the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|max_length[32]|valid_email|callback_email_available');
```

Controller method

```
public function email_available($str)
{
    // You can access $_POST variable
    $this->load->model('mymodel');
    $result =   $this->mymodel->emailAvailability($_POST['email']);
    if ($result)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('email_available', 'The %s already exists');
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Model mymodel.php

```
public function emailAvailability($email)
{
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $query  =   $this->db->get('tablename');
    return $query->row();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Extend the Form_validation library by adding a class like `MY_Form_validation.php` in your `/application/core` folder (assuming your subclass prefix is `MY`, which it is with default settings. This is a quick example, which just inverts the existing `is_unique` function by changing the last line from `return $query->num_rows() === 0;`.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends Form_validation
{
    /**
     * Match one field to others
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   field
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function is_not_unique($str, $field)
    {
        list($table, $field)=explode('.', $field);
        $query = $this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str));

        return $query->num_rows() > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Putting above code in application/libraries worked for me in CI 3.1.11.

Answer (score 0):

Try your own callback function

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|max_length[32]|valid_email|callback_email_check');
```

Function will be something like this

```
public function email_check($str)
    {
        if ($str == 'test@test.com')
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('email_check', 'The %s field can not be the word "test@test.com"');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```