# valid_email not working along with callback function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hello all i was using form_validation Library in codeigniter inside my application. I am making a password retrieving function. I have made a submit form of the email . Now, on the email input field i want to apply these validations.

1. required
2. valid_email
3. check email exist or not.

For the 3rd one i am using call back function to check the database and it worked fine. But with the call back function valid_email is not functioning. This is my controller functions.

```
     public function password_retrieve()
    {
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback__email_exists');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $this->load->view('login_header');
            $this->load->view('password_retrieve');
            $this->load->view('login_footer');
        } else {

        }
    } else {
        $this->load->view('login_header');
        $this->load->view('password_retrieve');
        $this->load->view('login_footer');
    }
    }

    function _email_exists($email)
    {
    $this->load->model('users_model');

    $result = $result = $this->users_model->check_email_is_exist($email);
    if (!$result) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message(__FUNCTION__, 'This %s address does not exist!');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    }
```

It should checked the valid_email rather than the going to the callback function.

In other mean i want to know what is the order of the rules. Is callback rule runs before the valid_email?

Comment: valid_email is a native rule so no reason it shouldn't work... What email are you trying?

Comment: i tried using test and it directly says this doesnot exist. ignoring the valid_email rule

Comment: why there is an underscore `_` in  function name. just remove it and try. just `email_exists($email)`

Comment: tried already still not succeeded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14452606/4514250  see this

Comment: @ParagSoni this is not near to what i want!

Comment: So are you saying that if I typed in myemailaddressatfluffybunnies as an invalid email, you are seeing the error message saying "This email address does not exist" instead of the standard Invalid Email error message?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw exactly sir!

Comment: And if you remove the custom callback from the rule, then you see the correct message?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw yeah it worked fine and smoothly. giving error of valid email.

Comment: Just out of interest - what version of CI are you using?

Comment: codeigniter 3 sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148482/discussion-between-timbrownlaw-and-adeel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Searching the official documentation and `git` repository i have found out that there is not a particular order in which a function will run in codeigniter. This means `$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback__email_exists');` 
In this case valid_email will run after the `callback__email_exists`. There is not a order in which first `trim`, then `required` and then `valid_email` will run.

So what i have done is to make a new function in my `callback` function which runs after the required but before the `check_email`.

Answering this question so that in future people can get the benefit from it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "trim" and for check if email exist don't use another function. But use "is_unique[table_name.email]".

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[table_name.email]');
```

Comment: i am checking reverse of is_unique. Read my question again. also removing trim did not work either.

Comment: i want to check if not unique. because of email already being in the database

Comment: The input of the email in the html the type is set on text or email?

Comment: It is set to the text

Comment: then try to set to email and leave the valid_email.

Comment: sir i think you are not getting my question. I dont want to use front end validation. What is the use of form_validation library if i want to use the front end validation? What if somebody changed it to text in console?